# Postgresql 9 table lock resolution

Tags: postgresql

I have an `ALTER TABLE` statement that according to `pg_stat` is "waiting", and I'm wondering if there is an easy fix to allow the statement to execute?

From my limited understanding I think it's a table level lock that isn't releasing. The table `pg_locks` shows a single `AccessExclusiveLock` that has its granted column set to `f`. Running `ps aux | grep postgres` confirms that there is a postgres `ALTER TABLE` waiting.

If it helps the statement is one that's been created by the Django ORM (South in particular).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is most probably another transaction open that did a select on that table.

Look for sessions that are " in transaction".

Make sure they end their transaction (so that the sessions shows "" or if you cannot do that, kill them with `pg_terminate_backend()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of sessions that are in transaction you can use a [query to list the processes blocked and the PID these are blocking on](http://ghostwritten-insomnia.blogspot.de/2013/04/show-blocking-postgres-processes-and.html).

Make sure you don't run `pg_dump` while trying to apply your schema migrations.